# Can I set search_path when importing a shape file with ogr2ogr from GDAL?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal

I'm importing shape files into Postgresql via this command:

`ogr2ogr PG:host=localhost dbname=someDbName user=someUserName password=somePassword shapeFile.shp -nln alternateLayerName -nlt someValidGeometry`

This works well but goes into `public` schema in Postgresql. I'd like to choose a different schema. Is there a way to achieve this with `ogr2ogr` alone?

There's no reference in `man ogr2ogr` to *schema*. My web search wasn't fruitful either.

I know I can do an `ALTER TABLE some_table set schema a_different_schema`, but that would mean adding another step to the process.

`$ ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a better web search I found on [GDAL pg driver documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html) that one can use `ACTIVE_SCHEMA=string: Active schema.` to set the schema where the table will be created.

I tried it like this:

`ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=mydb active_schema=layers" country.shp -nln test_table -nlt MULTILINESTRING`

And it complains with:

`ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed: invalid connection option "active_schema"`

But table gets created and populated properly. So I guess it's ok.

Comment: It seems indeed that the error should not be reported, because it gets imported fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution by using `lco` option:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=some_db
user=postgres password=" someShapeFile.shp -nln desiredTableName
-nlt someValidGeometry -lco SCHEMA=desiredPostgresqlSchema
```